# I know basic gates but not their structure

Tags: digital-logic

I know everything except the structure of logic gates. Recently a HighOrderThinkingSkill question asked the gate from structure where I was totally stumped please help me:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC1o6d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where A and B are input and :
$$1\to>5V\\0\to<1V$$

How to find and be prepared for future questions?

The answer key says it's an AND gate, but I don't understand why.

[image]

Comment: Usually I solve these by trying combinations of 0V and 5V on A and B - if you solve for Vout in each case, you can get a good idea of what's happening.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon if anyone of the input is 0(<1V) both diodes are forward biased and so current will flow , so i think it's OR

Comment: Also: this circuit looks really strange, because Vout is tied to Vcc. Are you sure this schematic is accurate?

Comment: @Gregd'Eon yes.

Comment: ok - looks like @Camil's answer covers everything here then.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon i haven't solved any such circuit yet.

Comment: check the textbook publisher's website - there should be an errata. vout can't be directly connected to vout, that's clearly a mistake. schematics are hard to proofread.

Comment: Id agree with @MarkU, the schematic does not look correct. Vout will always be Vcc regardless of what A and B are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analyse the working of the circuit for all possible values of A and B. Write down a truth table of A, B and the output. Then you should recognise a pattern.

In this case, note that the output is directly connected to 6V. What does that tell you?

Comment: w8 and see my edit

Comment: i suppose it's OR because if any of the input are low then diode is forward biased and current flows?

Comment: @ADG it can't be OR: when A=B=0, output is still 1, while 0 OR 0 = 0. Just make the truth table. What is the output value for every A, B?

Comment: sorry but i am even not getting how you are taking out the output?

Comment: remember i'm not yet enetered college.

Comment: @ADG you need to consider the question "What is the voltage at the output with respect to ground for certain values of A and B?" Do this for all possible A and B.

Comment: since node vcc is 6v so output is always 6v as it is connected by non resistive wires throught the branch.

Comment: @ADG you solved it! The output is always 1! :)

Comment: it's and according to answer key, should i post actual figure?

Comment: @ADG yes please. I'm pretty sure this circuit is not AND. Perhaps the 10K resistor should be on the Vcc side.

Comment: see the edit...

Comment: @ADG I'm sorry, your teacher is wrong. Tell him that since the output is tied to Vcc, the output will always have a potential of 6V with respect to ground, hence the output is always a logical 1.

Answer (score 2):

Where a logical 1 is equal to +V minus a diode drop, and a logical \$0\$ is equal to \$0\$ V plus a diode drop, using resistors and diodes it's only possible to construct AND and OR gates like this:
[image]
Inversion isn't possible and Y must either be pulled up - through a resistor - to +V for the AND function, or the polarities of the diodes reversed and Y pulled to GND through a resistor for the OR function, so none of the answers to problem 11 in your workbook is correct.